# BABEL Cannot find module 'node:path' error react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, babeljs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to setup [tailwindcss-react-native](https://tailwindcss-react-native.vercel.app/) package into my react native project. After successful installation when I add classnames to a component it gives me an error. I've tried uninstalling and then re-installing it, removing the npm cache and node_modules folder but I can't figure out what is wrong. I'm attaching the error log and also codes of my project. Please point out what I'm missing here. Thank you

[image: Screenshot of error log]

My babel.config.js file:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ["tailwindcss-react-native/babel"],
  };
};
```

My tailwind.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./screens/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

My App.js file:

```
import { TailwindProvider } from 'tailwindcss-react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <TailwindProvider>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </TailwindProvider>
    </NavigationContainer>
    
  );
}
```

My HomeScreen.js screen:

```
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

export default function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text className="text-red-500">HomeScreen</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

My dependencies & dev dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.7.0",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "tailwindcss-react-native": "^1.7.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/node": "^7.18.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.4"
  },
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is your node version...
All you need to do is update your node for the latest version,
delete package.json node_modules folder, and npm install

Answer (score 3):

For everyone who is getting this error, the solution is to update `Node` at least on `14.18.0`.
The `tailwindcss-react-native` package is trying to access the `node:path` variable that is available from version 14.18.0`

Answer (score 1):

The way i solved mine was to reinstall my app 
Then after it has been installed I removed the package-lock.json and node_modules and reinstalled tailwind-css-react-native and did a the setup in the documentation and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error while using Vite for component testing, then I realized, Vite uses node: import which is supported in v16.0.0+ and v14.18.0+. v15 does not support this.
https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#node-imports

Answer (score 0):

All you need do to fix this error is to

1. install the latest version of Node js.
2. Install this Babel plugin yarn add @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx --dev
3. Add this code to your babel config js  "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the guide here by installing

```
npm install nativewind
npm install --save-dev tailwindcss
```

https://www.nativewind.dev/guides/babel